# How can I achieve page-up and page-down in OS X?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I am using MacOSX Snow Leopard.

How do I achieve page-up and page-down?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

If you have a full keyboard you can use the pgup and pgdown keys on your keyboard, near the numpad.

If you are not using a full keyboard, function, labeled <kbd>fn</kbd> on your keyboard, plus the up and down arrow keys will give you a page up and down.

For certain applications, particularly in shell / terminal / tty windows, the expected behaviour is achieved with <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow up/down</kbd>

Comment: -1 actually FN+Up/Down is not the same as FN+PageUp/PageDown. For example, the traditional PageUp/PageDown does not work in irssi.

Comment: @hhh: It seems that irssi and some other terminal apps use `Shift`+`PgUp`/`PgDn`, so the key combination on a MBP would be `Shift`+`Fn`+`PgUp`/`PgDn`.

Comment: This is for the hardware mapping of these functions. OSX applications don't generally use these keys in the way most of us expect. ctrl+a and ctrl+e (home & end) are an option. My post below explains how to get the functionality you expect for the Terminal application. Each app handles these keys according to it's own settings. Strange.

Comment: This has not been my experience. I have the full size Apple Keyboard hooked up to my Mac Pro and these keys only work as expected outside of OSX. My post below shows how to alter Terminal so it'll work normally. But it was also helpful when I learned that in general OSX has CTRL+A as HOME and CTRL+E as END

Answer (score 39):

It's true that the hardware keyboard on Macintosh machines has:

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> = <kbd>Home</kbd>
<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> = <kbd>End</kbd>
<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> = <kbd>Pg up</kbd>
<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> = <kbd>Pg down</kbd>

So these "keys" fully exist already. This is apparent if you run Linux/Windows natively on your Mac.

However, macOS applications are responsible for handling these functions as they see fit, which is different from what you'd see on Windows or Linux. Therefore, the macOS Terminal application needs some tweaking to use these keys.

I believe the reason for this is that macOS follows an old-school Unix tradition where:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> = <kbd>Home</kbd>
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> = <kbd>End</kbd>

I now use this routinely, but my terminal-reflexes still demand a proper home,end,pg-up,pg-down...

**Edit macOS's Terminal Keyboard Binding Settings to match**

[image: home]
[image: end]
[image: page up]
[image: page down]

I tend to get this entered by copying a similar entry that already exists,  then using the 'delete a character' button, I remove the different bits before typing in the rest.

Overall, this will look along these lines:
[image: Match the home, end, pg up and pg down]

This meets all my expectations for how this should work. It works in vim and through ssh.

Comment: I think it's really funny which answer has been accepted for this question. I guess different strokes for different folks?

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, easier to read, and much more informative, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

On my (Danish) keyboard layout (under 10.7.5) it is <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>.

Comment: I have an US English keyboard and this is what works for me under terminal if I'm SSHed.

Comment: It works for me in the terminal regardless of whether I'm SSHed.

Comment: This works for shells in VirtualBox with U.S. Extended keyboard layout (under 10.10.5)

Answer (score 6):

It's <kbd>⌥</kbd> + Up/Down arrow keys.

Comment: This doesnt work for me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @hobs not sure, but I'm actually on Lion, works either way for me, with fn and ⌥

Comment: Same here, Macbook 13 inch running 10.7, I will look into it.

Comment: On OS X 10.6.8 I get about a 3-line scroll w/ opt+arrow versus actual PgUp PgDn behavior with the fn+arrow.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [KeyRemap4Macbook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) app, check under "Change Arrrow Up/Down/Left/Right" keys.

When you have this set up, Page Up and Page Down will work with [irrsi](http://www.irssi.org) – I log-on remotely to another linux host for that – you only need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>Page Down</kbd> will work for that window (as opposed to scrolling pages of OS X terminal window).

Answer (score 0):

PageUp:
Fn+UP

PageDown:
Fn+DOWN

Successfully tested on my brand new MBPro retina !

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS Catalina:

---

Scroll to the page-top - `cmd`+ `↑`

Scroll to the page-bottom - `cmd`+ `↓`

---

PageUp - `fn` + `↑`

PageDown - `fn` + `↓`

Comment: Interesting that Start+ArrowUp/Down works with and external (Windows-tailored )keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

user Fn

PageUp: Fn+UP
PageDown: Fn+DOWN

Comment: Is this different than the answer from December that also says to use Fn key? http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/113926/5472

Answer (score -1):

Alt + up/down arrows: pgup/pgdown

Spacebar and shift + spacebar: : pgup/pgdown

Command + up/down arrows: home/end

Comment: What do you mean by `Spacebar and shift + spacebar: : pgup/pgdown` ?

Comment: That one goes down and the other combination goes up.

Comment: No idea what you mean here since spacebar .. enters a space and shift-spacebar .. enters a space.