# PageUp and PageDown keys for Irssi (IRC) in Macbook?

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook-pro, command-line

I cannot find the keys on my mackbook. I need them to go page-up and page-down in irssi (IRC). I have tested the tips [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26930/how-can-i-achieve-page-up-and-page-down-in-os-x) but they do not work. They model some different Up/Down, not the traditional Up/Down as on larger keyboards.

**How can I press PageUp and PageDown buttons with Macbook? Irssi is running behind ssh and GNU Screen with UTF8 support.**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>

IIRC in previous versions of Mac OS X (Lion or perhaps earlier), fn had to come first. But I just tested fn vs. shift first and neither had a different effect.

This may be Terminal.app specific, and may not work in iTerm 2. YMMV

Comment: Thank you! Worked like charm with mountain lion, happy easter!

Answer (score 42):

It took me a while to guess that and I didn't find anything on Google, so at least, if somebody needs it, it's <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> in iTerm 2.

Comment: Brilliant, this saved me! I've used fn-shift-up/down for years and just upgraded to El Capitan and spent several days in confusion...

Comment: Ha, glad I could help! It's weird that this still gets upvotes when I'm not even using a Mac anymore, though. Something missing in iTerm's docs?

Comment: Same for `Terminal.app`

Comment: hey Huawei Matebook user brought here by search engine, this shall work for you too!

Answer (score 4):

In Terminal, go to Preferences... > Profiles. Click your 'Default' profile or the one you're currently using. Click the 'Keyboard' tab. Click 'Use Option as meta key'. Now Option-P and Option-N will do page back and page up.

Control-P and Control-N are view page up/down... so it's super nice.

Comment: This will disable all the cool characters that you can input via option key. What I'd like to have is option+n/p functioning, I made an [issue](https://github.com/irssi/irssi/issues/1448) about that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using irssi within tmux on Yosemite.

When using laptop keyboard (no number pad) this works: <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd>

or (mojave)

<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd>

When using a standard keyboard <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>page up</kbd>/<kbd>page down</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I'm using irssi on Mavericks. For me it was <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

On El Capitan with standard keyboard I got just <kbd>page up</kbd>/<kbd>page down</kbd> buttons to work fine out of the box.